# How to structure data: arrays in array

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to come up with a structure for my data. Let's imagine that I have a library. In this library, there are different books - I can add books to the library and delete them. So I guess I would need to start with an `NSMututableArray`:

```
NSMutableArray *entireLibrary;
```

Each book in this library has a certain set of features. Some require an array (such as different strings for the headings in each book) and other features, such as page length, require only an integer. The set of characteristics stays the same for each book, like so:

```
NSString *bookTitle;
NSMutableArray *chapterHeadings;
NSInteger *pageCount;
```

My question is what the best way would be to store all of this information in my library. Right now, I only have different arrays, strings or integers and I can't see how I can assign them to an individual book which is then placed in my library -- and how to access the data when I need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your own custom class called BookClass. Keep the bookTitle, chapterHeadings and pageCount as properties of that class and then add BookClass objects into the entireLibrary NSArray.